# How do I find lines that contain two | characters

Tags: notepad++

How do I find lines that contain two of these | characters.

EXAMPLE:

```
1 hellothere|hihowareyou
2 sasdfhellothere|hihowareyasdfou
3 hellothere|hihowareyou|
4 sasdfhellothere|hihowareyasdfou
```

Notepad++ would find line 3.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a regex search: switch the search mode to **Regular expression**.

Then find:

```
(.*\|){2}
```

Further, if you need to find lines with two *or more* `|` characters, find:

```
(.*\|){2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a regular expression search for `\|.*\|`. Make sure the "**. matches newline**" at the bottom of the search window is not ticked.